# Accessing Eventhub in spark streaming using managed identiry

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub, azure-managed-identity

I have a requirement where I need to access the eventhub stream in spark streaming(azure data bricks) but using manged identity authentication. Currently I see only the SAS key access in all the blog and documentation but not mentioned about manged identity.

would it be possible if someone can please guide me how to access eventhub in spark structure streaming with manged identity authentication ?

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: I dont think azure databricks supports managed identity (=> you can't assigned an identity to databricks).

Answer (score 1):

Right now managed identity isn't supported for Databricks clusters so you can't use it to access to EventHubs.

Please raise this request to a solution architect or customer success engineer assigned to your organization (if you have one of them)